# Not able to send html mail from rails 4.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, html-email

I have started sending mails from rails 4.0.8,but i am not able to send html mails,i created html view for my mailer but still its executing as text/plain.My mailer method given below(customer_mailer.rb)

```
  def X customer, message, cust_mail, email_subject
    subject = email_subject
    mail_ids=cust_mail.to_s.split(",")
    mail :subject => subject || "Your Invoice", :to => mail_ids, :body => message

  end
```

my html view (X.html.erb)

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#D6A1A1">

<table width="100%" bgcolor="#D6A1A1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am able to show static html page and how can i pass message to x.html.erb from method X. It started working when i removed following line ':body => message'

Comment: Just as a check have you specified in your development.rb `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` as by default it is false

Comment: i don’t have that line of code in my development.rb  file, i added that line in my file and tried but still i am facing same problem

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but executing as text/plain,i need to make html mail

Comment: can you add more code?how you calling that method , and did you configured in exact way?

Comment: i am calling method like  this    customer.welcome_mailer(params, current_user, customer_params)

Comment: Make sure you don't have  X.text.erb in your mailer view path.

Comment: Thanks, Now I am able to show static html page and how can i pass message to x.html.erb from method X. It started working when i removed following line ':body => message'

Answer (score 0):

change

```
mail :subject => subject || "Your Invoice", :to => mail_ids, :body => message
```

to

```
mail :subject => subject || "Your Invoice", :to => mail_ids, :body => message.html_part
```

this

These methods will just guess and find the first part in a multipart message of either text/plain or text/html content type. CloudMailin also provides these as convenience methods however via params[:plain] and params[:html]. It's worth remembering that the message is never guaranteed to have a plain or html part. It may be worth using something like the following to be sure:

```
plain_part = message.multipart? ? (message.text_part ? message.text_part.body.decoded : nil) : message.body.decoded
html_part = message.html_part ? message.html_part.body.decoded : nil
```

Comment: No, i used  "customer.welcome_mailer(params, current_user, customer_params)"

Comment: yea i am getting mail properly but text/plain format,i need that in html format

Comment: Just paste this in your customer/mailer model method - this will solve your problem
content_type  "text/html"

Comment: got this error   Caught exception : NoMethodError : undefined method `html_part' for #<String:0xb3e10470>
message i am passing from JavaScript its just string,passing that string through mail

Comment: Did you try this "message.html_part.body.decoded" ?